# inMobi ads to android

Tags: android, cordova, inmobi

I have an Android Cordova app. Now I want to add inMobi service advertising to this app, but I don't know how. Can anyone help ? Thank you so much. Because in android cordova project doesn't have xml file. So I don't know how to work with inMobi ads. Thank you.

Comment: Install Plugin For InMobi https://github.com/Blah2014/phonegap-inmobi-plugin and use

Comment: Naveen Tamrakar. It shows ad when I click on the button in body tag. But when I put <script> InMobi.showAd(); </script>  in head tag. It doesn't show anything.  Can you help me? I want ads show when the page load. But it doesn't work

Comment: Hello TAN. I'm from InMobi. We do not provide official support for Cordova unfortunately. You can perhaps contact the author of the plugin for help.